# partial user name upon installation of SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server-2017

I'm in the process of setting up a new laptop for application development work and today I installed SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition on this computer.  I used the Basic install option rather than the Customize install option.  Some pertinent facts:

- operating system is Windows 10
- device name is MARIGOLD
- administrator on this computer is an e-mail address and the characters that appear before the @ symbol for the e-mail are knot22

When the confirmation screen was displayed after installing SQL Server, it showed the SQL Administrator as `MARIGOLD\knot2` (see red line that points this out in screenshot).  Notice that there is a 2 missing - was was expected was `MARIGOLD\knot22`.  Why did it chop off the user name?  Is there a way to fix this?
[image]

Comment: What does the username look like in `C:\users\`?

Comment: It looks like this: `C:\users\knot2`.  A single 2 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your username on the computer is "knot2".

This may not match the display name.

**The following procedure will lose all stored credentials. You may lose program data, bookmarks contact lists... as well as some file permissions**

The easiest way to solve this is to:

1. Create a temporary admin account, Grant the account all privileges in SQL Server.
2. Login as that user.
3. Backup the entire `C:\users\knot2` directory(including hidden and system files). You may have to reboot to do this.
4. Delete the "knot2" user.
5. Create "knot22" user.
6. Grant the "knot22" account all privileges in SQL Server.
7. Copy the backup of `C:\users\knot2` into `C:\users\knot22`
8. Remove or disable the temporary user.

It is up to you to figure out if it is worth it or not.